# read multiple (JSON) files from a central config server in a spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, microservices

I would like to have a centralized configuration server (can be a web service) for multiple web services. Each service upon loading would contact this server and load the files that its interested in (based on a set of keys). I would like to host different types of configuration files and load corresponding ones for the requesting service. To keep things simple we can assume all the files are in JSON format.

I am wondering if there is a solution in spring boot/spring cloud to achieve the same. I looked into [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) , but looks like its reading individual properties and does not let me read the whole file and not sure if it would let me read multiple files.

**UPDATE**: I looked at spring-cloud-config as well. I had two questions there

1. Is it possible to customize the config server to my needs ?
2. Is it possible to serve multiple files (under a given path) as jsons ? assuming all the files are in json format.

Any pointers or suggestions for this requirement would be helpful.

Comment: You're looking for Spring Cloud Config.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Thanks for the recommendation. Please see my recent update about some questions i had after looking at spring cloud config.